# Spring Boot Batch sample example error

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a sample spring boot batch application that i run under spring boot 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT, when i run them i got this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 414; <Line 20, Column 414>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at cc.fr.suivireco.configuration.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: <Line 20, Column 414>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd'
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:428) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:290) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:415) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:236) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:175) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted


   Caused by: oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException: Duplicated definition for: 'identifiedType'
at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.buildSchema(XSDBuilder.java:1113) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.build(XSDBuilder.java:664) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDValidator.processSchemaLocation(XSDValidator.java:1060) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDValidator.startElement(XSDValidator.java:665) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1588) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:448) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:394) ~[xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar:na]
... 26 common frames omitted
```

i have not a context spring xml definition, i don't knew how to resolve it.

more detail [**here** >>> Duplicated definition for: **`identifiedType`  error #524**](https://github.com/oasp/oasp4j/issues/524)

Thank you

Comment: Why are you even using a 1.3.0 snapshot instead of 1.3.8 final (I suggest trying that at first). And apparently you clearly do have an xml configuration file else it wouldn't blow up with this exception.

Comment: this is the mother project configuration, it's for 1.3.0-snapshot, I do not think the problem comes from the Spring Boot version

Comment: That's not a conflict with spring boot tomcat ?

Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

The mother application uses a tomcat independent of that of spring boot

Comment: BTW why are using cxf, add your pom.xml